# Create centroid tag within a radius for longitude-latitude data in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, radius, geosphere

I have longitude-latitude data (220000  observation [duplicates included]) and I want to create two new columns defining the number of points within 5km and 10 km radius.

My problem is the vector size, meaning that the algorithm does not run for this size of data.

Here is my code to create the first column, `radius_5km`.

```
long <- runif(n=220000,min=-153,max=174)
lat <- runif(n=220000, min=-42,max=67)
df <- data.frame(long,lat)

library(geosphere)
dfgesphe <- cbind(df,Radius_5km=rowSums(distm(df[,c("long","lat")], 
   fun = distHaversine) / 1000 <= 5)) # number of points within distance 5 km
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to calculate. You want to how many points are within 5km of at least one other point? Your brute force approach will not work on the number of combinations.

Comment: Your title is confusing (it's so confusing that I didn't want to edit for fear of changing the meaning ...) - could you please edit?  I assume you will have to find a way to do this in chunks ...

Comment: I *think* OP wants to compute, for each point, the number of other observations within 5 and 10 km of that point (by great-circle distance). Maybe there are tools in `sf` for this?

Comment: My idea, is to count the number of points, for each coordinate, within a radius of 5km and 10 km. I m aware of the number of combinations to test. So, I asked to know if there is a better way to do it. I have already thought about creating a set of uniform radius circles and count the number of points that fall within each one.

Comment: You will likely need to perform the calculation using a divide-and-conquer approach.  Sort the data by longitude and then divide filter data into smaller chunks. Then you can use the distm function.  Of course you will have to adjust for points near the edge of the smaller sections.